# how to create 2 order by in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

i want to create sql req to twice use of order by in the same column i try with this exemple

```
SELECT  titleEN, smallDescriptionEN, StartDate, EndDate
            FROM event
            WHERE EndDate > NOW()
            ORDER BY StartDate ASC

UNION

SELECT  titleEN, smallDescriptionEN, StartDate, EndDate
                FROM event
                WHERE EndDate < NOW()
                ORDER BY StartDate DESC
```

but sql error indicated incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

```
#1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY
```

Comment: You can only have one ORDER BY here, at the end, will work for the complete UNION result.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I hope this is just an example? For there is no need for a UNION here at all. Simply write `WHERE StartDate < NOW() OR EndDate > NOW()`.

Comment: so what i do to use twice of order by to sort the events carried out in a manner ascending the opposite for future events

Comment: Your last edit changes the question completely. You should have accepted the answer given and place a new question instead.

Comment: What I understand now is: You want all records matching `EndDate > NOW()` first, odered by StarteDate ascending. After these you want all records matching `EndDate < NOW()` ordered by StartDate descending. You don't want any records matching `EndDate = NOW()`. Is all this correct?

Comment: yes that's exactly i want

Answer (score 0):

One `Order By` at the end is enough to Order the complete result set

```
SELECT titleEN,
       smallDescriptionEN,
       StartDate,
       EndDate
FROM   event
WHERE  EndDate < Now()
UNION
SELECT titleEN,
       smallDescriptionEN,
       StartDate,
       EndDate
FROM   event
WHERE  EndDate > Now()
ORDER  BY StartDate DESC;
```

Comment: so what i do to use twice of order by to sort the events carried out in a manner ascending the opposite for future events

Comment: @isom - Which DBMS you are using

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is just an example and assuming your business case is legit here is something that would od exactly what you are asking for:

```
DECLARE @tmpAsc AS TABLE (titleEN VARCHAR(MAX), smallDescriptionEN VARCHAR(MAX), 
    StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @tmpAsc
SELECT titleEN,
       smallDescriptionEN,
       StartDate,
       EndDate
FROM [EVENT]
WHERE EndDate > GETDATE()
ORDER BY StartDate DESC

DECLARE @tmpDesc AS TABLE (titleEN VARCHAR(MAX), smallDescriptionEN VARCHAR(MAX), 
    StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @tmpDesc
SELECT titleEN,
       smallDescriptionEN,
       StartDate,
       EndDate
FROM   [EVENT]
WHERE  EndDate < GETDATE()
ORDER  BY StartDate DESC;

SELECT * FROM @tmpAsc
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM @tmpDesc
```

Comment: A query without an ORDER BY clause is not guaranteed to retrieve the records in any specfic order. So while this approach may work in many cases, you must not rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already a unioned query has only one ORDER BY clause. If you want to sort one way or the other, you need a clause with a CASE construct:

```
SELECT  titleEN, smallDescriptionEN, StartDate, EndDate
FROM event
WHERE EndDate > NOW()
UNION ALL
SELECT  titleEN, smallDescriptionEN, StartDate, EndDate
FROM event
WHERE EndDate < NOW()
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN EndDate > NOW() THEN 1 ELSE 2 END -- "after now" before "before now"
  CASE WHEN EndDate < NOW() THEN StartDate ELSE NULL END DESC
  CASE WHEN EndDate > NOW() THEN StartDate ELSE NULL END ASC;
```

Or simply:

```
select  titleen, smalldescriptionen, startdate, enddate
from event
where enddate <> now()
order by (enddate < now()), abs(timestampdiff(second, now(), startdate)) desc;
```

Date/time operations are dbms specific (as are boolean expressions for that matter). This is for MySQL.